# Exactly what read/block guarantees does DataInputStream provide following available()

Tags: java, io, network-programming, datainputstream

I've read the java docs and a number of related questions but am unsure if the following is guaranteed to work:

I have a DataInputStream on a dedicated thread that continually reads small amounts of data, of known byte-size, from a very active connection. I'd like to alert the user when the stream becomes inactive (i.e. network goes down) so I've implemented the following:

```
...
streamState = waitOnStreamForState(stream, 4);
int i = stream.readInt();
...

private static int
waitOnStreamForState(DataInputStream stream, int nBytes) throws IOException {
    return waitOnStream(stream, nBytes, STREAM_ACTIVITY_THRESHOLD, STREAM_POLL_INTERVAL)
            ? STREAM_STATE_ACTIVE 
            : STREAM_STATE_INACTIVE;

private static boolean
waitOnStream(DataInputStream stream, int nBytes, long timeout, long pollInterval) throws IOException {
    int timeWaitingForAvailable = 0;
    while( stream.available() < nBytes ){
        if( timeWaitingForAvailable >= timeout && timeout > 0 ){
            return false;
        }
        try{
            Thread.sleep(pollInterval);
        }catch( InterruptedException e ){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return (stream.available() >= nBytes);
        }
        timeWaitingForAvailable += pollInterval;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The docs for available() explain:

> Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream **without blocking by the next caller of a method for this input stream**. The next caller might be the same thread or another thread. **A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.**

Does this mean it's possible the next read (inside readInt()) might only, for instance, read 2 bytes, and the subsequent read to finish retrieving the Integer could block? I realize readInt() is a method of the stream 'called next' but I presume it has to loop on a read call until it gets 4 bytes and the docs don't mention subsequent calls. In the above example is it possible that the readInt() call could still block even if waitOnStreamForState(stream, 4) returns STREAM_STATE_ACTIVE?

(and yes, I realize my timeout mechanism is not exact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean it's possible the next read (inside readInt()) might only, for instance, read 2 bytes, and the subsequent read to finish retrieving the Integer could block?

That's what it says. However at least the next `read()` won't block.

> I realize readInt() is a method of the stream 'called next' but I presume it has to loop on a read call until it gets 4 bytes and the docs don't mention subsequent calls. In the above example is it possible that the readInt() call could still block even if waitOnStreamForState(stream, 4) returns STREAM_STATE_ACTIVE?

That's what it says.

For example, consider SSL. You can tell that there is data available, but you can't tell how much without actually decrpyting it, so a JSSE implementation is free to:

- always return 0 from `available()` (this is what it used to do)
- always return 1 if the underlying socket's input stream has `available() > 0`, otherwise zero
- return the underlying socket input stream's `available()` value and rely on this wording to get it out of trouble if the actual plaintext data is less. (However the correct value might still be zero, if the cipher data consisted entirely of handshake messages or alerts.)

However you don't need any of this. All you need is a read timeout, set via `Socket.setSoTimeout()`, and a `catch` for `SocketTimeoutException`. There are few if any correct uses of `available()`: fewer and fewer as time goes on, it seems to me. You should certainly *not* waste time calling `sleep()`.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I though readInt etc. and available were methods of the same class. I considered the read timeout but worried about timing out mid-way through a readInt and not knowing where to pick up for the next read. I suppose I'd have to loop on each byte, catch the timeout, set the state, and then construct the Integer w/ something like ByteBuffer.wrap().getInt() ?

Comment: You're trying to detect down connections. If you get a read timeout within your timeout period, it's a down connection. It is *extremely* unlikely that you'll get one in the middle of `readInt()`, unless the peer is written very bizarrely, but if you do, it's still a timeout, and it's still eligible to be considered a down connection. I don't see what `readInt()` and `available()` being in the same or different classes has to do with it.

Comment: Because the docs say _without blocking by the next caller of a method for this stream_ so, thinking it was a method of the stream (not of a sub class), I thought readInt() wouldn't block. (I guess it's just a reading comprehension issue on my part.) If I use a 5 sec read timeout and the network only goes down for 10 sec,  why shouldn't I try to continue reading from the stream (after alerting the user) when it comes back up? readInt() uses 4 read() calls, how can I keep reading/parsing if I don't know which read() timed out and where I'm at in the stream?

Comment: @JonO. It's your timeout, you can do whatever you like with it. But if you're not interested in 10 second network outages, why would you set a 5 second timeout?

Comment: So I can alert the user that the real-time data they're expecting is delayed, while still waiting for it.

Comment: @JonO.That is now a completely different question from what you asked. What you asked about is, and I quote, 'network goes down', and that is detectable via a read timeout or a connection reset, and that's what I answered. If you just want to detect and notify *slowness*, see `ProgressMonitorInputStream`: if it exists for long enough, it will pop up visibly.